# How to divide two queries to get a fraction in rsql?

Tags: sql, rsql

I am trying to find the fraction of the results generated by these two queries:

Numerator value:

```
dbGetQuery(db2, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS number_tweets
           FROM tweets JOIN users
           ON tweets.user_id_str = users.user_id_str
           WHERE text LIKE '%brexit%'
           AND users.screen_name_in = '1'")
```

Denominator value:

```
dbGetQuery(db2, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS number_tweets
           FROM tweets JOIN users
           ON tweets.user_id_str = users.user_id_str
           WHERE users.screen_name_in = '1'")
```

I have tried using subqueries but I always get 0 as the answer. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here:

```
dbGetQuery(db2, "SELECT x.number / y.number 
           FROM
           
           (SELECT COUNT(*) AS number
           FROM tweets JOIN users
           ON tweets.user_id_str = users.user_id_str
           WHERE text LIKE '%brexit%'
           AND users.screen_name_in = '1') x
           
           JOIN
           
           (SELECT COUNT(*) AS number
           FROM tweets JOIN users
           ON tweets.user_id_str = users.user_id_str
           WHERE users.screen_name_in = '1') y on 1=1
           
           ")
```

Tried this as well from comment, but get 0:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in a single SELECT query by moving your WHERE condition into a SUM function:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(text LIKE '%brexit%', 1, 0)) / COUNT(*) AS myCalculation
FROM tweets JOIN users
ON tweets.user_id_str = users.user_id_str
WHERE users.screen_name_in = '1'
```

This adds up all the rows where `text LIKE '%brexit%'` and divides by the total rows.

Comment: I still get 0 as the result which is very weird..

Comment: I added the screenshot above. Individually the queries return the numbers but combining it gives me 0

Comment: I see the data type is an INT. Is the result getting rounded to 0?

Comment: Also, you're using `IIF` instead of `IF`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: To debug, run the following query which will let you know what the values of the SUM and COUNT are separately: 
`SELECT SUM(IF(text LIKE '%brexit%', 1, 0)) / COUNT(*) AS myCalculation, SUM(IF(text LIKE '%brexit%', 1, 0)) AS numLikeBrexit, COUNT(*) AS numRows
FROM tweets JOIN users
ON tweets.user_id_str = users.user_id_str
WHERE users.screen_name_in = '1'`

Comment: I use IIF because its sqllite. I tried that and get the picture above

Comment: myCalculation is still 0

Comment: @RheaRamtohul The problem is that your calculation is a decimal value (approx 0.047 based on the results in your latest picture) but the data type is INT so the decimal portion is lost. You need to convert the type to DECIMAL, otherwise you will get a result of 0.